turning off ipv6 on macos 15
Turning off ipv6 on macos 14 worked fine with sudo networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi.
Has anything changed with 15 that this has stopped working?
I still see ipv6 traffic even after turning off ipv6 traffic with sudo networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi
